# Configure Wildfly Swarm for SSL

Tags: ssl, https, jax-rs, wildfly-swarm

I try to configure Wildfly Swarm to use SSL to enable HTTPS Connections. My Application has only an REST API Endpoint (JAX-RS). I found some information about classic Wildfy, using the standalone.xml for configuration. 
I  understand that I could use standalone.xml as well, but I am not sure if I can put this configuration ind the project-defaults.yml as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring SSL in `project-defaults.yml` is definitely possible. I have an example project doing this here: https://github.com/Ladicek/swarm-test-suite/tree/master/protocols/https. It doesn't use JAX-RS, merely Servlet, but should be enough.

The relevant part of `project-defaults.yml` looks like this:

```
swarm:
  https:
    keystore:
      path: ${project.build.directory}/keystore.jks
      password: password
    key:
      alias: httpskey
      password: password
```

EDIT: if you have a keystore with a *single* entry whose password is the *same* as the keystore password, you don't need the `key.alias` and `key.password` properties. In such case, this would be perfectly enough:

```
swarm:
  https:
    keystore:
      path: ${project.build.directory}/keystore.jks
      password: password
```

(This is actually the case in the example project, so you can clone it and try :-) )

Comment: Thank you @Ladicek, that was very helpful.

Comment: what about setting also a truststore for mutual TLS authentication?