# Configure HTTPS connection for REST API in Wildfly Swarm

Tags: rest, https, wildfly-swarm

I like to provide my REST API (JAX-RS) through an HTTPS connection. I use wildfly swarm and deploy the application in OpenShift.
I did the configuration as mentioned here: [Configure Wildfly Swarm for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294778/configure-wildfly-swarm-for-ssl)

But something is still missing. Do I have to setup a HttpListener manually?

Comment: If you want SSL on OpenShift, why don't you just configure an edge-terminating secured route and leave the WildFly Swarm application unsecured? See https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html#secured-routes

Comment: This is prohibited by our InfoSec...Don't ask...

Comment: OK, so, if you run the app locally, does HTTPS work? Or is it only that it doesn't work on OpenShift? You will still need a passthrough secured route, I believe.

Comment: I made it running locally with HTTPS and also on OpenShift. I didn't configure to use the management fraction, which seems to be needed for the HTTPS Listener

Comment: Oh yeah, the `management` fraction is required for configuring the security realms. It's too easy to forget, happened to me many times.